# How to display an array of integers in a JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jtextarea

```
for (int j =0; j < marks.size(); j++) {
    analyzeTextArea.setText(j + marks.get(j));
}
```

The above code gives me the following error:

```
required: java.lang.String found: int
```

Comment: Once you've figured the basics, consider using a `JTable` (2D array) or a `JList`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess `marks.get(j)` give you an Integer. So when you do `j + marks.get(j)` you add the value of `marks.get(j)` to the value of `j`.

So you end with an Integer as result of `j + marks.get(j)`. But `setText` expect a String.

You have several possibilities now depending on you needs.

```
analyzeTextArea.setText(Integer.toString(j + marks.get(j)));
```

This case still make the addition then convert it to String in order to respect `setText` parameter type.

With this :

```
analyzeTextArea.setText("" + (j + marks.get(j)));
```

`""` tells that the parameter will be a String and then you will concatenate `j` and `marks.get(j)`. So, for example, for the first loop you will have something that start with `0`

Now using `setText` in a loop don't really make sense because only the last value set in the loop will be used you probably should use [JTextArea#append(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: +1 for "This is why it's not working, try this" and not "do this, it works"

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like this:

```
analyzeTextArea.setText("" + (j + marks.get(j)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
analyzeTextArea.setText(Integer.toString(j + marks.get(j)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
for (int j =0; j < marks.size(); j++) {
    analyzeTextArea.setText(j + marks.get(j)+"");
    }
```

Comment: second solution will give an error because `int` doesn't have a `toString()` method

Answer (score 1):

That should work but instead of .setText(), you should use .append(). because .setText() deletes the previous contents and writes it. but .append() just adds on information